# J-TAG DEBUGGER OF 14 PIN?

Tags: jtag

can any one suggest me which jtag debugger(14 pin) is suitable for ARM7TDMI-S Processor ?.

thanks in advance.

regards,

kumaraswamy

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about the 14-pins: There are adapters from the normal ARM 20-pin header to the old 14-pin layout. 
E.g. this one: http://www.lauterbach.com/order/ord_ad7747.html
However it should be rather simple to build one by your own.

So the tricky thing is to find a debugger, which supports ARM7TDMI. I know that Lauterbach has one and I assume iSystems has one too. These are both very good but also rather expensive tools I think, but I assume that there are no cheap tools out there for such an old CPU core.